# Something about limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I learned the following:
$\forall n \exists k_0 : \forall k\ge k_0: |a_k - a^*|<n$. And my textbook also pointed that you can pick some n, let's say $n=1/k$. But that's my struggle; then you can choose anything for n? But then there is always a way for the equation to be true? And so every sequence must have a limit?

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the use of $n$ is quite confusing since usually it denotes something going to infinity, for infinitely small values one usually use $\varepsilon$. See e.g. P. Halmos:

> A mathematician’s nightmare is a sequence $n_ε$ that tends to $0$ as $ε$
>   becomes infinite.

So, the definition of 
$$
\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k = a^*
$$
is: for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $k_0(\varepsilon)$ such that for all $k>k_0(\varepsilon)$ it holds that $|a_k-a^*|<\varepsilon$.

So, formally you need to check that the condition above holds for all $\varepsilon>0$. Fortunately, it is equivalent to check for only sequence of $\varepsilon$ which is positive and converge to zero itself (quite recursive, though). Clearly, $\varepsilon_i = \frac1i$ is one of the examples.

I hope I understand you post correctly, because $n=\frac1k$ leads to a question which $k$ do you mean?